# How to change the Path from the terminal

Tags: path, terminal, cmd, directory

Is there a way to add to the path from the terminal in Windows, as opposed to from the GUI. Further, can you add the *current* directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set path=%cd%;%path%
```

will set the current directory into the path for this particular instance of `cmd`.

You'd need to invoke `setx` to save the changed path permanently for future instances. See

```
setx /?
```

from the prompt for directions.